# Php $value as an array learning

Tags: php

I'm just learning PHP as I go and I've come across a basic task I need some help understanding.

I have a dataset that contains multiple values. I want to display an output based on the values as they are found.

```
$value = "1, 2, 5, 7";

If ($value = 1) print "One, "
If ($value = 2) print "Two, "
If ($value = 3) print "Three, "
If ($value = 4) print "Four, "
If ($value = 5) print "Five, "
If ($value = 6) print "Six, "
If ($value = 7) print "Seven, "
```

Expected output would be One, Two, Five, Seven,

I've tried switch, case and that works fine on datasets where I have one value in the data set. But doesn't work if there are multiple values. I'm assuming I need to define $value as an array in order to achieve this?

Comment: Please __provide data sample__ which causes "doesn't work". People are here to help and not to guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be using an array.

```
$value = [1, 2, 5, 7];
```

If your dataset is a string, you can convert it to an array easily buy splitting on the comma and trimming any whitespace (for CSV style data):

```
$value = "1, 2, 5, 7";
$newValue = array_map('trim', explode(',', $value));
// $newValue is now [1, 2, 5, 7];
```

You can check if a value is contained inside the array with [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array(5, $value)) {
    echo "The number 5 is in the dataset!";
}
```

There are tons of functions you can do with arrays to sort, filter, and do pretty much whatever you want with your dataset: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to learn how you would structure this program and what tools can get you there, then here is some information on tools available.

First thing to do would be to convert this data to an array, using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$valueArray = explode(',', $value);
```

Then you'd want to iterate over it with [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($valueArray as $data) {
}
```

Finally you could utilize the [`NumberFormatter` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php) on the data items after wrangling their types:

```
$wrangledData = (int)trim($data);
$spelledOut = NumberFormatter::format($wrangledData, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
```

And you could return it back to a string with [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$value = implode(', ', $valueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your values in an array and check to see if they are in the array. And as you'll find out `=` is for assignment not comparison which is `==`.

```
$value = [1, 2, 5, 7];

If (in_array(1,$value)) print "One, ";
If (in_array(2,$value)) print "Two, ";
If (in_array(3,$value)) print "Three, ";
If (in_array(4,$value)) print "Four, ";
If (in_array(5,$value)) print "Five, ";
If (in_array(6,$value)) print "Six, ";
If (in_array(7,$value)) print "Seven, ";**
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if this is a substitution(translation) problem:

```
<?php

$value = "1, 2, 5, 7";

$map = [
    1 => 'One',
    2 => 'Two',
    3 => 'Three',
    4 => 'Four',
    5 => 'Five',
    6 => 'Six',
    7 => 'Seven'
];

print strtr($value, $map);
```

Output:

```
One, Two, Five, Seven
```